# COM - avoid implementing IUnknown repeatedly

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, inheritance, com

I am trying to implement a basic Browser Helper Object for Internet Explorer. I have 2 classes, one that must implement IClassFactory and one that must implement IObjectWithSite. Both these interfaces inherit from IUnknown. To avoid implementing IUnknown repeatedly, I created a base class Unknown so that for a given child class I only need to implement it's direct parent interface. Here are my class declarations:

```
class Child1 : public Unknown<IObjectWithSite>

class Child2 : public Unknown<IClassFactory>

template <class T>
class Unknown : public T
```

I've done it this way to avoid the Diamond Problem.

```
Child1 ---> Unknown ---> IObjectWithSite

Child2 ---> Unknown ---> IClassFactory
```

In Unknown I implement the IUnknown methods that it will inherit from T.

I can't seem to get this to work. Am I missing something here? Have I gone about it the wrong way?

EDIT: here's the code below

Unknown.h

```
#pragma once

#include <OCIdl.h>
#include <Unknwn.h>

template <class T>
class Unknown : public T
{

protected:

    // Reference count to this COM class
    ULONG m_comRef;

public:

    // IUnknown methods
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        // Implementation...
    }

};
```

Child1.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Unknown.h"

template <class T>
class Child1 : public Unknown<T>
{

public:

    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject);

};

STDMETHODIMP Child1<IClassFactory>::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) {
    // implementation...
}

etc...
```

Child2:

```
#pragma once

#include "Unknown.h"

template <class T>
class Child2 : public Unknown<T>
{

public:

    STDMETHODIMP SetSite(IUnknown*);

    STDMETHODIMP GetSite(REFIID, void**);

    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject);

};

STDMETHODIMP Child2<IObjectWithSite>::SetSite(IUnknown*) {
     // Implementation...
}

etc...
```

Comment: What does "I can't seem to get this to work" mean? It doesn't compile? It doesn't run? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Many. The first build error I get is pointing me to the definition of Child2 saying "use of class template requires template argument list".

Comment: You should post your original code, the one you had when you posted the question, and tell which line gives the error.  Note also that this isn't really solving any diamong problem, it's only avoiding you to implement `IUnknown`'s methods over and over again.  However, it seems you want to override `QueryInterface` in subclasses, so it only avoids you to reimplement `AddRef` and `Release`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your child class declaration to:

```
template <class T>
class Child1 : public Unknown<T>
```

You're instantiate the parent template in the class declaration, it is not allowed.

In the function implementation, you still need use T:

```
template <class T>
STDMETHODIMP Child2<T>::SetSite(IUnknown*) {
     // Implementation...
}
```

For your problem, you don't need declare 2 child class,  you can simple use:

```
Unknown<IObjectWithSite> child1;
Unknown<IClassFactory> child2;
```

when instantiating a template, the compiler creates a new type, so `Unknown<IObjectWithSite>` and  `Unknown<IClassFactory>` are different types with IUnknown implemented.

Comment: Right. And in my implementation I specify the actual type argument? Like Child1<IObjectWithSite>::myMethod. And would a default constructor work here?

Comment: Ok I've tried this but no luck. I have the declaration of Unknown in a header file and I'm including this in the header files for the declarations of Child1 and Child2. As these 3 classes are templates the implementation is also included in the header file. I'm still getting "Unknown: use of class template requires template argument list" even though Child1 (and Child2) are declared like this: template <class T> class Child1 : public Unknown<T>

Comment: I've edited the question with the code included now.

Comment: I have the 2 child classes because I need to implement other interfaces apart from IUnknown. Why would I not need them? Also, surely I need pass the actual argument for the type parameter when im implementing the method?

Comment: `Child1` and `Child2` don't have to be templates.  Boon, please consider posting your original code, not the templates version.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are going about it wrong.  Use ATL. Spend your time writing functionality instead of reimplementing IUnknown, and IClassFactory.

Comment: I'm completely new to COM and haven't used ATL before either. So I wanted to start from a bare bones approach to understand COM better.

Comment: Links, for example to existing `IUnknown` [implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/iunknown-implementation-classes?view=vs-2019), and and example would have made the answer better.